# WCF service oneway operation timeout

Tags: wcf, service, operation

Does the OneWay operations in WCF service execute as long as the operation is complete or is there any operation timeout for oneway wcf service.

If there is as such any operation timeout configuration then please tell me I want to increase it so that one way wcf service should take as much time it want to execute operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an execution timeout for WCF operations marked as OneWay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636686/is-there-an-execution-timeout-for-wcf-operations-marked-as-oneway)

Answer (score 1):

Try configure the bindings to the WCF service found in app.config.

> system.servicemodel > bindings > .. > opentimeout / sendtimeout

More information on configuration settings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx)

Comment: But at service side I want to increase execution timeout of operation it executing not the send ,recieve, open and close timeout.

Comment: How do you service the WCF service? Website / windows service?

Comment: Right, you've asked this question 5 different times?? Forget it find it out yourself

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the channel as IContextChannel.  This interface has an OperationTimeout property you can set.  It's location is different from the usual Open, Close and Connect Timeouts that are located on the proxy.